# Get Requests count per IP per request in Nginx access.log

Tags: unix, nginx, devops

I have unix server running nginx **Debian GNU/Linux 9**

I am trying to get requests count per IP per request in Nginx access.log file for analysis, so
I have 2 questions:

1. is there a unix command to fetch this info from the log file (the whole file), per ip per request?
2. also is it possible to filter it by date?, i mean get the requests count per IP per request in a certain day. so hopefully i get something like this

> ```
> IP        count
> 127.0.0.1 4
> 127.0.0.2 5
> 127.0.0.3 6
> ```

i found this, but it just counts ips

```
sudo awk '{print $1}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use grep in the first command :

```
grep '12/Jan/2021' access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

and for certain date using extended regular expression :

```
grep -E '11/Jan/2021|12/Jan/2021' access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20
```